Clip spatial data to polygon in python
Good day, I am trying to create a spatial plot of gridded precipitation data. I have opened the netCDF using xarray. However, the data is currently not land-only (Figure 1) and I want it to only cover the land area. I have previously used a land-sea mask to mask out the ocean grid points, however at this fine resolution, I loose data that is partially inland (Figure 2).


Is there a way to use the polygon for the country border to crop the data within that region?
Here is my plotting code:
# Plot for mean annual rainfall
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=1, subplot_kw={'projection': ccrs.PlateCarree()}, figsize=[10,6])

lev_prp=(0,100,200,300,400,500,600,700,800,900,1000,1100,1200)

im0 = ds1am.rnd24[16][0].plot.contourf(cmap=colourmap_prec, extend='max', add_colorbar=False, levels=lev_prp)

plt.colorbar(im0, fraction=0.035)

axes.set_xticks([26, 28], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axes.set_yticks([-32, -34], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
axes.add_feature(cf.BORDERS, alpha=0.5)
axes.add_feature(cf.COASTLINE, alpha=0.5)

plt.tight_layout()


See the last paragraph of this post

Note that, since Matplotlib v3.8 the collections attribute used at @JohanC's link is deprecated.  However, you can now set the clip path for the whole contour plot https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/whats_new_3.8.0.html#clipping-for-contour-plots
